# Natural sort using DPL on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, natural-sort

Using the DPL extension, with ordermethod = title, is there a way to trigger natural sorting, such that for a series of pages with titles with numberic dismabiguations, the result gives B below, rather than A below?  By default, you get A.

A:

```
PageName (something 1)
PageName (something 10)
PageName (something 2)
..
PageName (something 9)
```

B:

```
PageName (something 1)
PageName (something 2)
..
PageName (something 9)
PageName (something 10)
```

Comment: Did you try using sortkey magic word for pages `{{DEFAULTSORT:key}}` ( https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words ) ?

Comment: The DPL results are outside of the context of mediawiki's sorting, I think.

Comment: Have you tried setting the collation? https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCategoryCollation

Comment: @Nemo, that sets it for native Category listings.  DPL is an extension - the collation setting you reference wouldn't apply.